# jqueryui slider with disabled regions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-slider

Can I have active and inactive regions in a jqueryui slider? Something like this:

[image]

Here, the two handles should not be slide-able in the white region.

I tried to find solutions, but couldn't come up with any.

**EDIT:**

I require such design to select a time between a given interval, where a part of interval  can't be selected.

For example: I need to select a time between 12:00 PM and 6:00 PM, but selection is not allowed between 1:00 PM and 2:00 PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution using simple CSS hack, though it uses multiple sliders.

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider1" class="slider"></div>
<div id="slider2" class="slider"></div>
<div id="slider3" class="slider"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    border-radius:0;
}
#slider1{
    width:50px;
}
#slider2{
    width:100px;
    background:#ddd;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
}
#slider2 a{
    display:none;
}
#slider3{
    width:75px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.slider').slider();
```

Here's a **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/quq0wnkx/1/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do this?

Is it not a better solution to have two separate sliders?

You need to supply us with more information, such as the application of this, because as far as I understand you cannot do this with properties of the slider, however you may be able to do this with some hackish JS.

Comment: I have added the situation where I need such design in the question..please check

Comment: I would set up one slider, and when you submit the value, you can check if it is within the 1:00PM - 2:00PM Range and prompt the user to choose a different value. I am not sure how you would 'disable' the slider between those values.

Comment: That would be a bit annoying to the user, since there might be more than one such inactive regions.

Comment: Well what are you expecting to happen when the slider is in the 'disabled' region? 

If you want, you can check the value of the slider, and if you are within the disabled region you can disable the button that inputs this data.

Comment: Again, it's the same thing. What I was looking for, was to present the user with the possible ranges that can be selected i.e. the user should know beforehand the possible ranges for selection just by looking at the slider.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to accomplish this the way you would like to.

Comment: Check this link out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067148/jquery-slider-time-picker-and-reserved-times

Comment: seems helpful, will try to implement.

Comment: supposedly if we are using multiple sliders, how about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/quq0wnkx/

Comment: That should work, with some crafty CSS I'm sure you could make it looks like there is only 1 slider instead of multiple.

Comment: How does this look? http://jsfiddle.net/gunja4q2/
** EDIT ** I updated the link to a better version.

Comment: I posted an answer without any pixel calculations. Check. :)

Comment: I would recommend marking your question as answered and giving credit to those that have helped you, as you might have difficulties getting responses to questions that you might have in the future as people generally do not want to answer questions for a user that does not give credit.